# Cookie Sharing Between ASP.Net Core 2.2 and ASP.Net 4.6, with ASP.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have followed this article to implement cookie sharing between an ASP.Net Core 2.2 MVC app with ASP.Net Core Identity, and an ASP.Net Framework 4.6 MVC app with ASP.Net Identity:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

---

The article mentions that a common user database must be used:

"***Use a common user database***

*Confirm that the identity system for each app is pointed at the same user database. Otherwise, the identity system produces failures at runtime when it attempts to match the information in the authentication cookie against the information in its database.*"

---

I've noticed that there are some slight schema differences between the ASP.Net Core Identity tables--AspNetUsers tables, etc.--and the ASP.Net (standard) Identity tables.

The 'common user database' I'm using contains the ASP.Net Core version of the Identity tables.

I've not been able to get cookie sharing to fully work, because the column, "LockOutEndDateUtc", which was a part of the prior version of the AspNetUsers table, is no longer in the table--specifically, the column is now "LockoutEnd".

Because of the missing LockOutEndDateUtc column, an error is thrown when calling Authentication.User.Identity.GetUserId() from the ASP.Net 4.6 application, which is pointed to the common user database that contains the ASP.Net Core version of the Identity tables. Based on this, I wonder if there might be additional issues when sharing cookies between ASP.Net 4.6 and ASP.Net Core 2.2 apps.

Has anyone else run in to this problem? And/or what is the best way to proceed?

(I can add the column to the AspNetUsers table and get past the issue; however, I would imagine that there is a proper/common way to address this.)